# Parsing HTML with HTMLDocument class in C#

Tags: html-parsing

I want to get all the anchor () nodes of HTML from HTMLDocument object that have attribute href but should not have a title attribute

Comment: yes, using HtmlAgilityPack use document.DcomentNode.select(xPath); where xPath will be "//a"

Comment: `document.DcomentNode.select(xPath)` will select all links, how you filter the links without `title` attribute ?

Comment: we can iterate for the links that have title attribute null - well i was askin for a solution where i need not iterate but with iteration this is possible but yet i dont know how to do this using xPath